# Get jquery plugin options from data-* attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to do something like that:

```
<ul class="handle" data-option="9000">

$('.handle').pluginName({
    option: $('this').data('option'),
});
```

where $('this') should target the $('.handle') which is being initialized.

Comment: It is if you have an element looking like `<this></this>` ?

Comment: @adeneo nope, I want to target $('.handle')

Comment: I get that, but right now you're targeting an element with the tagname `this`, as you've quoted it, hence the comment above. And as @undefined stated, there is no scope, so `this` would be the parent scope and not the element.

Comment: @adeneo thank you, I got that, I did with an each loop as answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't, you can loop through the elements:

```
$('.handle').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.pluginName({ option: $this.data('option') });
});
```

Or if you are the plugin's author read the `data-*` attributes in your plugin.

Comment: no I am not the author, that's why i am asking, you answer worked, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

no apostrophes around "this" and it should work like in this example:

```
$('.handle').each( function() {
    alert( $(this).data('option') );
} );
```